# Rudin Chp. 5, q13: Proving that $f'(0)$ exists only if $a > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Rudin Chp. 5 q. 13:
>
> Suppose $a$ and $c$ are real numbers, $c > 0$, and $f$ is defined on $[-1, 1]$ by
>
> $$f(x) = x^a \sin(|x|^{-c}), x≠0$$
> $$f(x) = 0, x=0$$
>
> (b) $f'(0)$ exists iff $a > 1$

To me, it seems quite clear that $a>1$ would work because it is intuitively clear that $f(x) → 0$ as $x → 0$. The function $\sin(u)$ has a range of $[-1, 1]$, so while $\sin(|x|^{-c})$ will oscillate infinitely as $x→0$, $x^a → 0$ for $a > 0$. It is clear that this is continuous for $a>0$.

But I need to show that it is differentiable for $x=0$ iff $a>1$. And this is where I have gotten stuck. I am able to show that it is *not* differentiable for $a ≤ 1$. But when I try to show it is differentiable for $a>1$, I fail to do so. I tried to differentiate $f(x)$ in general ($f'(x)$) then show it will not work as $x→0$ for $a≤1$, but this method does not work with $a>1$, and I end up with $x^{a+1} / |x|^{-c-2}$ (plus unimportant constants and cosine). And that is bad because, for example, if a = 2 and c = 10, that limit clearly diverges to infinity.

A fellow student claimed to used the definition of the derivative to solve this and I tried this:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{t→x} \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x} = \lim_{t→x} \frac{t^a \sin|t|^{-c} - x^a \sin|x|^{-c}}{t-x}$$

And we are interested in only $f'(0)$, so we can simply:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{t→0} \frac{f(t) - f(0)}{t-0} = \lim_{t→0} \frac{t^a \sin|t|^{-c} - 0}{t}= \lim_{t→0} t^{a-1} \sin|t|^{-c}$$
Assume $a>1$
$$=\left[\lim_{t→0} t^{a-1}\right]\left[\lim_{t→0}\sin |t|^{-c}\right] = 0\left[\lim_{t→0}\sin|t|^{-c}\right] = 0$$
This is clear because $\sin(u)$ has a range of [-1, 1].

Clearly in the case that $a≤1$, this will diverge.

Is this all that I need to do? I don't understand why my first method did not work but the second did, if that is indeed all I must do.

I am worried about the main concept, not about how my “proof” looks. I can write it out MUCH better on paper, I am struggling to format this well on the computer (and sorry for this!)

Comment: Hello, sorry for the poor formatting and other issues, but my computer started to suffer from extreme lag writing this out and I am not very good with all the formatting tools on this website. I hope this is understandable and someone is willing to fix up my mess! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think there is a small typo in the question: the function should probably read

$$f(x)=|x|^a \sin(|x|^{-c}), $$
for otherwise, if $a=\frac{3}{2}$ say, there is a problem with
$$f(-1)=\color{red}{(-1)^{3/2}} \sin(1). $$

Other than that, you shouldn't always rely on the equality

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) $$
which is not always true.

A third remark, as noted by Michael is that you've written the expression

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \sin(|t|^{-c}) $$

although it doesn't exists. I understand that it looks like the multiplication by 0 "kills" it anyway, but that's not how you write that down.

Comment: That is another bit that I was worried about. It appears that it could create complex values. But then I realized I am only interested in $f'(0)$, so I don't think that really matters, does it?

Comment: @zagadka314 Since the limit in the derivative should work from both the negative and the positive direction, you want $f(x)$ to make sense even for small negative values of $x$. The author probably meant to add that missing absolute value for that purpose.

Comment: the solution manual says this:
What do $x^a$ and $x^{-c}$ mean for $x<0$? In general these will be complex-valued functions. It might be better to use absolute values in both cases. Thus we shall amend the problem by defining $f(x) = |x|^a sin(|x|^{-c})$. 

I am not sure why it would matter, complex limits should also work, shouldn't they?

Comment: @zagadka314 Complex powers are much more complicated. How would you interpret $(-1)^{\pi}$ for example? (there are infinitely many possible candidates.)

Comment: I used the definition of the derivative and then set $x=0$. $f(0)=0$ according to the definition of $f$. Is this not a valid way to solve for $f'(0)$?

Comment: @zagadka314 your way was fine, but the proper way to say the limit is zero is to use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I was curious about that before, and google gave me: -0.902685362 - 0.430301217 i. Which is very interesting to me… Next semester I will take complex analysis, I hope to learn more about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

From $\lim_{t\to0}t^{a-1}\sin(|t|^{-c})$, I would use the Squeeze Theorem, since this is between $-|t|^{a-1}$ and $|t|^{a-1}$.  You have written the limit of the sine, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't think about that. I was using that _concept_ but didn't write it out that way. Thank you for that!

Comment: I hope my post isn't too messy.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my post!